# Git ignore issues

Tags: git, drupal-7, gitignore

How do I excluded a directory from being tracked by Git? My Git ignore entry does not work.

I've got a confusing issue with my Drupal website in which I am using two Git repositories.

The basic structure of the site is : *var/www/Intranet/sites/intranet*

In the **Intranet/sites/intranet** is my first Git repository which is where I maintain custom and contributed code using Git to version control.

In order to version control the Drupal core code base, I initiated a new GIT repository at `var/www/Intranet`. This new repo is meant to track everything except the contents of the **sites** sub directory. To this end I added `sites` to the .gitignore file.

But, what I've noticed recently is when I go to `var/www/Intranet/sites`, it is still being tracked by the new Git repo (`var/www/Intranet`) which should NOT be the case.

I'm not sure why that is happening.

Comment: Is it possible that you (or someone else) tracked the files you mention in an earlier commit ?

In that case, you will need to untrack them by hand.

Comment: @LeGEC: I tried to remove the sites sub directory from GIT tracking but the feedback, (git rm --cached sites && fatal: pathspec 'sites' did not match any files), suggests it was NOT previously being tracked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I first misread your question.)*

If you have two nested git repos :

```
Intranet   # <- repo1
+- .git/
+- sites/
 +- intranet  # <- repo2
  +- .git/
```

- from `repo1`, git will automatically find out that `sites/intranet` is another repo, and not try to track anything inside it,
- from `repo2`, git will show you the history of `repo2`, and report any changes for files in `repo2`

---

If you run a flat `git log` from anywhere within the repository, you will see the history of the whole repository.

If you want to check what changes affected a particular file or directory (a path) :
you should run `git log [path]`

If you run `git log sites/` for example (or equivalently : `cd sites/; git log .`) you should see that nothing has ever been commited in the `sites/` directory.

Likewise :

- `git status` will output info about files of the whole repo
- `git status [path]` will restrict its output to files contained in `[path]`

Comment: Sorry if I was being unclear. The issue is that when I change into Intranet/sites, GIT evidently at work within that directory and you can see the logs of the parent directory. My issue is that it shouldn't because I included *sites* in the .gitignore file

Comment: you mean : running `git log` from within `sites/` displays the history of `repo1` ? This is the expected behavior.

Comment: @sisko: Does `git log .` (<- note the extra '.') from `sites/` display any commit ?

Comment: "git log" from the sites directory shows commits for Repo#1. However, "git log ." does not show any commits.

Comment: @sisko: this means that, as expected, no commits have affected the content of the `sites/` directory. Do you see some other things which would lead you to think that `sites/` is not ignored ?

Comment: I've been giving this a lot of thought and I wish I was clearer on this issue but you are correct. I'm just confused why sites/ (though set to be ignored by git) shows git status data for it's parent directory. To me it seems like a bug.